# RobotFramework - How to Return Value from Keyword and Stop?

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to return a value from a keyword and exit keyword, just like you would do it in a programming language when you return values from functions. The keyword selects a random item from the list on the page, but if the page contains only 1 item then the whole thing crashes. I can't come to a solution and this is what i've done atm:

```
Get Random Item From Page
    # Pass the general list items xpath to the argument
    [Arguments]  ${element_path}
    ${elements}=  Get Element Count  ${element_path}
    Run Keyword If  ${elements} == 1  [Return]  ${element_path}[1]
    ${random}=  FakerLibrary.Random Int  1  ${elements}
    [Return]  ${element_path}[${random}]
```

The problem is that it continues to execute the keywords after the first return tag. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can take a look at [Return From Keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Return%20From%20Keyword) and `Return From Keyword If`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Return from keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Return%20From%20Keyword) or [Return from keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Return%20From%20Keyword%20If) to return from the middle of a keyword.

### Example

```
*** Keywords ***
Is number even or odd?
    [Arguments]  ${number}
    log  number is ${number}
    Return from keyword if  int('${number}')%2 == 0  even
    Return from keyword  odd

*** Test cases ***
Test even number
    ${result}=  Is number even or odd?  4
    should be equal  ${result}  even

Test odd number
    ${result}=  Is number even or odd?  5
    should be equal  ${result}  odd
```

Comment: Bryan Oakley's answer made in March 2018 is correct; however, there has been an update, and it is worth pointing out here.

 NOTE: Robot Framework 5.0 added support for native RETURN statement that is recommended over this keyword. In the examples below, Return From Keyword can simply be replaced with RETURN. In addition to that, native IF syntax (new in RF 4.0) or inline IF syntax (new in RF 5.0) can be used instead of Run Keyword If. For example, the first example below could be written like this instead:
IF    ${rc} < 0    RETURN 
This keyword will eventually be deprecated and removed.

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Return%20From%20Keyword